# How do I deal with brightness rescaling after FFT'ing and spatially filtering images?

Tags: image, filtering, fft, spatial

Louise here. I've recently started experimenting with Fourier transforming images and spatially filtering them. For example, here's one of a fireplace, high-pass filtered to remove everything above ten cycles per image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iO1Y.png - first image (sorry, I can't post images on Stack Overflow because I haven't got enough reputation).

As we can see, the image is very dark. However, if we rescale it to [0,1] we get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iO1Y.png - second image

and if we raise everything in the image to the power of -0.5 (we can't raise to positive powers as the image data is all between 0 and 1, and would thus get smaller), we get this:

same link - third image

My question is: how should we deal with reductions in dynamic range due to hi/low pass filtering? I've seen lots of filtered images online and they all seemed to have similar brightness profiles to the original image, without manipulation.

Should I be leaving the centre pixel of the frequency domain (the DC value) alone, and not removing it when low-pass filtering?

Is there a commonplace transform (like histogram equalisation) that I should be using after the filtering?

Or should I just interpret the brightness reduction as normal, because some of the information in the image has been removed?

Thanks for the advice :)
Best,
Louise

Comment: I think maintaining the DC value would be the simplest way of accomplishing this. Your image links are broken btw.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try that.
Image links work fine here :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Connor, the best way to preserve brightness is to keep the origin (DC) value unchanged. It is common practise. This way you will get similar image as your [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sigxt.png), because you do not change the average gray level of the image. Removing it using high-pass filtering will set its value to 0 and some scaling is needed afterwards.